# Referencing an external library in an Ant build

Tags: java, ant

We have an ant build script for a project we're developing for a PDA.  In eclipse we have a load of referenced libraries and I know how to get them to work when we run the jar on the PDA because we have a .lnk file where you can add the external libraries simply by adding the following:

```
512#"\J9\PPRO11\bin\j9.exe" -jcl:ppro11 -cp "\dist\WiFiTest.jar;\placelab\lib\placelab.jar" j2medemo.wifi.WiFiTest
```

Adding whatever libraries we need after the -cp argument.  However, I have no idea how to replicate this in the ant file (no idea is actually an exaggeration but after reading all the documentation I *still* don't understand it).

We have the following .

```
<target name="jar" depends="prepare">
 <delete file="${dist}/${appname}.jar"/>
 <delete file="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF"/>
 <manifest file="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF">
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="j2medemo.GUI.MapPanel"/>
</manifest>
<jar destfile="${dist}/${appname}.jar"
     basedir="${classes}"
     includes="**/*.class, **/*.jpg, **/*.gif,**/*.png,**/*.xml"
     manifest="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF"
     />
</target>
```

I have tried adding  everywhere I can think of but it doesn't help.  Can I just add it to the the include part?

Secondly, we have a run target:

```
<target name="run" description="run" depends="jar">
    <exec dir="${j9bin}" executable="${j9bin}\j9.exe">
        <arg line="-jcl:ppro11 -cp '${dist}\${appname}.jar;placelab\lib\placelab.jar' ${mainclass}"/>
        <env key="JAVA_HOME" path="${j9home}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

And I wanted to change it to run a different class so I created the following two targets:

```
<target name="jarSAX" depends="prepare">
 <delete file="${dist}/SAXParse.jar"/>
 <delete file="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF"/>
 <manifest file="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF">
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="j2medemo.Routes.SAXParse"/>
</manifest>
<jar destfile="${dist}/SAXParse.jar"
     basedir="${classes}"
     includes="**/*.class, **/*.jpg, **/*.gif,**/*.png,**/*.xml"
     manifest="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF"
     />
</target>
```

And

```
<target name="runSAXParser" description="run" depends="jarSAX">
        <exec dir="${j9bin}" executable="${j9bin}\j9.exe">
            <arg line="-jcl:ppro11 -cp '${dist}\SAXParse.jar' j2medemo.Routes.SAXParse"/>
            <env key="JAVA_HOME" path="${j9home}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

But if I try and run this I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: j2medemo.Routes.SAXParse
```

If anyone has any ideas/solutions for either questions that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you need to add the classpath elements to the manifest. Should look something like this:

```
 <manifest file="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF">
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="j2medemo.Routes.SAXParse"/>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="WiFiTest.jar;placelab.jar"/>
 </manifest>
```

The classpath entries should be relative to the location of the Jar in the distributable.  From there, you should be able to execute the jar directly (using the -jar command line option, I'm not sure what this is for J9).  Should be similar to the analogous Java call:

```
java -jar MainJar.jar
```